# Show $a_1 \mathbb Z · a_2 \mathbb Z$ = $(a_1 · a_2)$ · $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, integers

> Let $a_1$, $a_2$ ∈ $\mathbb Z$, Show:
>
> $a_1 \mathbb Z · a_2 \mathbb Z$ = $(a_1 · a_2)$ · $\mathbb Z$
>
> where $c\mathbb Z = \{c · n : n ∈ \mathbb Z\}$

My attempt:

Let $x$ ∈ $a_1 \mathbb Z$ then $x$ can be written as $x = a_1.n$ for some $n$ ∈ $\mathbb Z$

Let $y$ ∈ $a_2 \mathbb Z$ then $y$ can be written as $y = a_2.m$ for some $m$ ∈ $\mathbb Z$

Let $z$ ∈ $(a_1.a_2) \mathbb Z$ then $z$ can be written as $z = (a_1.a_2).l$ for some $l$ ∈ $\mathbb Z$

$x.y = a_1.n . a_2.m$ = $a_1. a_2. n. m$ since multiplication is commutative in $\mathbb Z$

But since $l$ ∈  $\mathbb Z$, it can be written as a linear combination, say $l = n.m$ so $z = (a_1.a_2).l = a_1. a_2. n. m = x.y$, and hence $x.y=z$ and thus $x.y$ ∈  $(a_1 · a_2)$ · $\mathbb Z$, and therefore $a_1 \mathbb Z · a_2 \mathbb Z$ = $(a_1 · a_2)$ · $\mathbb Z$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: What is your question now?

Comment: Is what I did correct?

Comment: And how do you define the product of two sets? From your question I think to infer as elementwise multiplication, is this the case?

Comment: @ JOJO, yes it seems to be.

Comment: @JOJO The idea is ok, but the details are a little messy. The bullet-proof way to prove that two sets are equal is to prove they both contain each other. It seems you're trying to do both things at the same time (proving that both $(a_1\mathbb{Z})(a_2\mathbb{Z})\subseteq (a_1a_2)\mathbb{Z}$ and $(a_1a_2)\mathbb{Z}\subseteq(a_1\mathbb{Z})(a_2\mathbb{Z})$). Could you do those two things separately and show your work for us?: 1. Prove that $(a_1\mathbb{Z})(a_2\mathbb{Z})\subseteq (a_1a_2)\mathbb{Z}$; 2. Prove that $(a_1a_2)\mathbb{Z}\subseteq(a_1\mathbb{Z})(a_2\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is lacking a bit of clarity in its presentation. You start by defining an arbitrary element, $x \in a_1 \Bbb{Z}$, then an unrelated arbitrary element $y \in a_2 \Bbb{Z}$, and finally, a third arbitrary element $z \in (a_1 a_2) \Bbb{Z}$, seemingly unrelated to both $x$ and $y$. In the final paragraph, you seem to change $z$ to now relate to $x$ and $y$, and in particular, so that it simplifies to $xy$.

It would be better if you declared $x$ and $y$ (and deduced the existence of $m$ and $n$ as you have), then let $z = (a_1a_2)(mn)$. You can conclude that $z \in (a_1a_2)\Bbb{Z}$, and that $z = xy$. This means $xy \in (a_1a_2)\Bbb{Z}$, as required.

This way, you don't have to pretend $z$ is arbitrary initially, and you only need to define it once it becomes useful to your proof. You could even skip defining $z$, and note that $xy = (a_1a_2)(mn) \in (a_1a_2)\Bbb{Z}$.

Also, bear in mind that all you've proven is $(a_1 \Bbb{Z})(a_2 \Bbb{Z}) \subseteq (a_1a_2) \Bbb{Z}$. You also need a separate argument for the converse direction. That is, you need to be able to start with some arbitrary $z \in (a_1a_2) \Bbb{Z}$ and construct elements of $x \in a_1 \Bbb{Z}$ and $y \in a_2 \Bbb{Z}$, such that $z = xy$. Hint: $1$ is a perfectly fine integer.

Comment: to show the converse direction: let $z = (a_1.a_2).l$ and let $x = a_1.n$ and $y=a_2.m$ so $x.y=z$ and so $(a_1.a_2)\mathbb Z$ ⊆ $(a_1\mathbb Z)$ $(a_2\mathbb Z)$. is this correct?

Comment: @JOJO Not really; you've got a related issue of simply declaring $x$ and $y$ to have the properties you want, rather than proving such numbers exist. What are $x$ and $y$, specifically, in terms of $z$? You know the existence of $l$, from the fact that $z \in (a_1 a_2) \Bbb{Z}$. How do you know $m$ and $n$ exist that fit your specifications? If somebody came to you with $170 \in 10\Bbb{Z}$ and asked you for the specific numbers $x \in 2\Bbb{Z}$ and $y \in 5\Bbb{Z}$ so that $xy = 170$, your proof should be a recipe for finding specific such values for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Show two inclusions in a systematic way:

Let $z \in a \Bbb Z \cdot b \Bbb Z$. This means that we can write $z=xy$ for some $x \in a \Bbb Z $ and $y \in \Bbb Z $. By definition we then know there is some $n \in \Bbb Z $ and some $m \in \Bbb Z $ such that $x=an$ and $y=bm$. 
Then we can conclude that (using standard commutative ring properties of $\Bbb Z $)

$$z=xy=(an)(bm)=(ab)(nm)$$ and because $nm \in \Bbb Z $ we conclude that $z \in (ab) \Bbb Z $, showing one inclusion.

Now let $z \in (ab) \Bbb Z $ be given. By definition this means that $z=(ab)n$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z $. Again using simple ring facts:

$$z=(ab)n= (an)(b1) \in a \Bbb Z \cdot b \Bbb Z $$

where the last step is by definitions again: $an \in a \Bbb Z $, $b1 \in b \Bbb Z $ and so their product is in the product of the sets.

Both inclusions being shown, equality is shown too. The only "clever(ish)" bit is that we use $1$ as an integer in the reverse inclusion. The rest should write itself.

Comment: by "$b1$", you mean $b.1$?

Comment: @JOJO yes. But I thought you reserved $\cdot$ for the set multiplication and just wrote $ab$ for multiplication in $\Bbb Z$. I followed that convention. I see you use a low dot instead of the TeX symbol `\cdot` (central dot).